# What does robocopy /XC actually do?

Tags: robocopy

The [robocopy documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) from Microsoft states that the `/xc` flag/switch means robocopy "*excludes changed files*". But what does that really mean?

I tried to test this with the following example:

- I made a text file and copied it to a destination folder with robocopy
- Then I made a change to the original source file
- Ran robocopy with `/xc` to see if it managed to exclude the changed file
- It didn't...

So how is `/xc` supposed to work?